# calculate total combinations of observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable with few values for that. 
Example: Var1 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

How can i find the total 2 letter combinations possible? eg: AB, AC, AD etc.

Here the list i have mentioned is small but in general I have a huge list and need to find total two letter combinations possible with all the values present for the variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Cartesian join will give you every combination against every combination, so a self join here will give you all possibilities. I usually use Proc SQL:

```
 Proc sql;
    create table cartesian1 as
        select * from table1,table1;
 Quit;
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not give me the dataset as I need it to be. The result I have got after using the above code was something like A 8 times and B 8 times and C 8 times and so on. The output dataset had 64 observations(8*8). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the table you want?  I'm assuming that you want all 2 letter combinations rather than permutations (i.e. order is not relevant).

```
data have;
input var1 $;
datalines;
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
;
run;

data want;
set have nobs=nobs;
length two_way $2;
do i=_n_+1 to nobs;
    set have (rename=(var1=temp)) point=i;
two_way=cats(var1,temp);
keep two_way;
output;
end;
run;
```